# Facebook App - Publish notes to timeline publically

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got an app that posts notes to a users timeline. I have the code working just fine, but I can't seem to get the notes to be public on the timeline.

I've added just about every permission (via permissions debug tool) and have tried turning every setting (both account profile & app settings) to post publicaly, but to no avail.

Any ideas gals and guys?

Update:
Oops, I had my app in sandbox mode; switching that off seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: Could you update your question with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change app from `sandbox=enabled` to `sandbox=disabled` in the developer setttings